# How to protect or secured ASP.NET MVC from XSS?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, security, asp.net-mvc-5

I'm creating a web application using the latest version of ASP.NET MVC 5.2.3. I just concern in XSS attack. I figure out in ASP.NET Core is perfectly working protecting from this attack the XSS and this framework totally amazing but it lacked third party I need to my project. Here's my concern. I already enabled the custom error too but I disabled it currently for testing.

But I want to make sure this will catch also.

1. Input Validation is passed. To avoid this exception or error.

A potentially dangerous Request.Form value was detected from the client (Name="").

using, the [AllowHtml] attribute this is fine or using the AntiXss library.

2. But, from the URL. Example URLs,

   http://localhost:54642/Employees/

   ```
   http://localhost:54642/Employees/?a=<script>
   ```

[link or url](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IOF6E.png)

this error should like,

A potentially dangerous Request.Path value was detected from the client (<).

So my solution is enabling this from Web.config then it works!

But Troy Hunt said from his tutorial this is not a good or better practice for this error. So I decided to look the best solution from this XSS attack.

Answer (score 3):

In my form I normally add this anti-forgery token

```
 @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
```

then on my controller I made sure validate the token

```
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
```

also when passing the variable or data, I always declare correct variable. Anyways if its member area page you can always restrict access to correct member roles example like

```
  [Authorize] // for registered user

  or more filtered

  [Authorize(Roles = "SUBSCRIBER.VIEW")]
```

Below is only applicable for .net 4.5 and above

```
  // web.config 
  <system.Web> 
     <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5" />
  </system.Web>

 // enabling anti-xss 
   <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5" encoderType="System.Web.Security.AntiXss.AntiXssEncoder,System.Web, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" />
```

> Request validation Lazy validation was introduced in ASP.NET 4.5, I
>   just did some testing on it and it seems that lazy validation is the
>   enabled regardless of how you set the "requestValidationMode", after
>   you've installed the 4.5 framework.

Comment: thanks, but this is for CSRF attack, I need XSS security.

Comment: without tag  [AllowHtml] on your input it should already protect your forms but  if you still dont trust your form you can use this AntiXss.AntiXssEncoder.

Comment: for the url protection example, localhost:8080/Employees/<script> how to protect from this?

Comment: it should auto-detect if you have this on your web.config <httpRuntime requestValidationMode if not like I mention on comment you may use this AntiXss.HtmlAttributeEncode(value).. I'll add it on my answer on more brief detail

Answer (score 1):

Check out OWASP site.  Here is the common ones I add in system.web in web.config file of a webapi app.

```
<httpProtocol>
  <customHeaders>
    <remove name="Server" />
    <remove name="X-Powered-By" />
    <remove name="X-Frame-Options" />
    <remove name="X-XSS-Protection" />
    <remove name="X-Content-Type-Options" />
    <remove name="Cache-Control" />
    <remove name="Pragma" />
    <remove name="Expires" />
    <remove name="Content-Security-Policy"/>
    <clear />
    <add name="X-Frame-Options" value="DENY" />
    <add name="X-XSS-Protection" value="1; mode=block"/>
    <add name="X-Content-Type-Options" value="nosniff" />
    <add name="Cache-Control" value="no-cache, no-store" />
    <add name="Pragma" value="no-cache" />
    <add name="Expires" value="Sun, 1 Jan 2017 00:00:00 UTC" />
    <add name="Content-Security-Policy" value="default-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' data; img-src https://*;"/>
  </customHeaders>
</httpProtocol>
```